# Nunit Test. Visual Studio. Namespace , class issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

.I m very new to programming, and I think I'm loosing my mind trying to understand what's the problem here. Does Anyone have any suggestions?

The Test Project has Reference set to OrderManagementSystem.Domain and  OrderManagementSystem.Controllers.
The Controllers Class is Public .
Im able to access Classes from Domain Namespace , but not Controllers??
What did i  do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Show us the controllers file. Also, please don't use screenshots for code, you can copy/paste code and format it directly in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because your class name is `Controllers` and namespace also contains `.Controllers`.

Either update the name of class or remove `.Controllers` from the namespace `OrderManagementSystem.Controllers`

**In Controllers.cs file,**

```
using Systems;
....

//Remove .Controllers from namespace
namespace OrderManagementSystems
{
    public class Controllers
    {
          //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, small issue but it worked.
The very annoying is that i was able to access Controllers Class from my UI Project without an issue, so that why it was so confusing to me.